# How do i add icon for taskbar in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, icons

I'm not sure whats happened but when i use to change the icon in application it would automatically change the taskbar icon, however it doesn't seem to be the case, is there something i'm missing?, thanks

[image]

Comment: Could be caching. Is the icon pinned? Is is it correct after a reboot?

Comment: i haven't pinned it but could be caching ill try a restart!

Comment: have tried a restart, nothing! is so weird

Comment: [Reset icon cache](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-reset-icon-cache-database-windows-10)?

Comment: just done this hasn't changed, im so boggled haha :)

Comment: You have to change form's icon too.

Comment: Thanks i'v just realised, i now feel stupid haha, thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to change form's icon too. – Hidayet R. Colkusu

need to edit the form property and change the icon there!

Answer (score 0):

Right click the Forms window, change its icon properties.

[image: Image example - Form Properties]

Application settings will only change the icon for the base Form I believe. (Form1)